# Deploying GWT Module to a subdirectory of /war

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Is it possible to deploy a GWT Module to a subdirectory of the /war folder? I tried using rename-to="folder/modulename" but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Don't change your rename-to attribute, keep it as-is. Just copy the generated folder to a sub-directory in your war.

For example, if your module is named as foo, GWT will create a top level folder named foo. This foo is usually inside the war directory, like this /war/foo. You can move it to a sub-directory like /war/my-sub-dir/foo and that's all there is to it.

Comment: It isn't possible to do this at gwt compile? We're in development of an GWT Application, and then we'll have to move it every time.

Comment: You can use ant to move the directory. Or you can keep the gwt module at the base location but move the host html page to a sub-directory.